# Could use Vim (-like bindings) in ipython notebook. Any workaround for Jupyter?

Tags: javascript, vim, ipython, jupyter-notebook, codemirror

It was possible to use codemirror's vim mode in ipython notebook by generally following the way explained [here](http://spaceli.wordpress.com/2013/10/04/add-vim-key-bindings-for-ipython-1-0-0/) and I was enjoying it, but in 2.x it's not possible because the notebook's interface "steals" escape key.
In fact, "Esc" in codemirror's vim mode is Ctrl-c, which is not working nevertheless.

I don't know anything about Javascript, but it seems codemirror's vim.js located in

...\IPython\html\static\components\codemirror

somehow maps Ctrl-c to Esc, but this Esc is presumably taken by ipython notebook.

Mixing ipython notebook and vim keyboard binding was a great environment. Is there any workaround in 2.x? Because of this, I'm still using 1.2.1.

## EDIT (Solution to 3.x/Jupyter):

~~Vimception does not work on 3.x(Jupyter) but I found that [this guy did a great job.](https://github.com/asford/notebook_input_mode) This works perfectly.~~

## EDIT2

Just see @Λlisue's answer. He deserves +100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is now a plugin for enabling codemirror vim mode with extra features:

https://github.com/ivanov/ipython-vimception

I've been using it since I saw the SciPy video. It has some little problems, but it works.

(Video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p9gnhmX1sPo)

Comment: Does this work in windows? I can't find anything on this on the github page.

Answer (score 7):

Recently I made a new plugin for enabling Vim key binding in Jupyter.
Try https://github.com/lambdalisue/jupyter-vim-binding